Can I use a galvanized well casing as a ground
I'm installing a sub panel the main is at the pole I have a galvanized well casing over 6' away from the first ground rod can I use the well as my second

Best ground rod you can get, unless it's abnormally shallow - and even then, you know it's wet on the lower end!

Quick lookup of code references says yes. At the very least, the casing should be bonded to the ground system.

250.50 Grounding Electrode System. All grounding electrodes
as described in 250.52(A)(1) through (A)(7) that are
present at each building or structure served shall be bonded
together to form the grounding electrode system. Where
none of these grounding electrodes exist, one or more of
the grounding electrodes specified in 250.52(A)(4) through
(A)(8) shall be installed and used.


250.52 Grounding Electrodes.
(A) Electrodes Permitted for Grounding.
(1) Metal Underground Water Pipe. A metal underground water pipe in direct contact with the earth for 3.0 m (10 ft) or more (including any metal well casing effectively bonded to the pipe)


250.112 (M) Metal Well Casings. Where a submersible pump is used in a metal well casing, the well casing shall be bonded to the pump circuit equipment grounding conductor.

